# How to conditionally use SQL and ORACLE database with C# and Entity Framework 6?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, oracle

I have developed a C# Windows application. I want to use SQL Server and Oracle database (conditionally) with Entity Framework 6.

Currently only SQL Server and Entity Framework are implemented in the application. It's working fine. But the client made a request to add Oracle database support in our application.

The database will be switched based on user-selected options.

Application user will select dropdown option (during login) to use SQL Server or Oracle. In the dropdown, only these two values as a string 1) SQL Server and 2) Oracle will be available.

When the user selects Oracle and continues in application, then the whole application with Entity Framework needs to work against an Oracle database.

Also if user wants to switch to SQL Server, then whole application with Entity Framework must work with the SQL Server database. It depends on the user's choice during login.

I don't have proper solution for this multiple database use with same application code based on user selected option (SQL Server or Oracle); I am looking for the best solution for implementing this functionality with an error-free and easy way to implement in existing application without having to re-write code.

**Application structure**

I used repository pattern functionality (same as web app but little difference in services dependency injection).

(Following all are separated projects with class library and UI-Form)

- UI project: Forms and C# code
- Model project: for custom model
- Abstraction project: for repositories and services interface only
- Service project: all the service will be called from UI action buttons (Save, Update, Delete)
- Repository project: all repository to get, update, save data in the database
- Database project: `.EDMX` model and generated all other files

Thanks in advance

Comment: Just use an Oracle provider for EF. The rest of the code won't change. That's explained in the docs by the way. You don't provide any other info, or any code, so there's no way to say what else should be changed. Perhaps all that's needed is passing a different connection name to the DbContext constructor

Comment: One of the nice things of ORM's like Entity Framework is that they provide an abstraction of the database specific queries. If both the Oracle and SQL Server databases do have the same structure, it changing the database would be pretty straightforward

Comment: If you are using Entity there is an EDMX mapping file.  The mapping file will need to contain both the SQL and ORACLE mappings.  Entity creates a class object for each table in each database.  I do not know if htere are any overlaps between the SQL and Oracle databases.   You also will need a different connection string for each database.  It may be better to create two class projects (one for Oracle and one for SQL) and then call the class project depending on which option is selected in a main project.

Comment: I am looking for some practical implementation example.